# Passing in a struct to a function and assigning it

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Sorry if this has already been ask before, but I got a little confused with passing in and assigning values to structs.

```
typedef struct test {
    int x;
    int y;
} test_t;

void func(test_t * test)
{
    test_t second;
    second.x = 2;
    second.y = 3;

    *test = second;
 }

void main()
{
    test_t first;
    func(&first);
}
```

Is this valid? If I remember correctly, without mallocing the struct inside func(), you shouldn't assign the pointer *test in func() to the struct second because its scope is primarily inside func() and will be lost once the function is returned. However, the values are correct when printed out in main().

What are the different ways to achieve this result? This is just to clear up some confusion and a forgetful memory.

Edit:

A clearer example of what I'm trying to do would be this:

```
typedef struct args
{
    int status;
    int id;
    unsigned long long start_address;
    unsigned long long end_address;
    unsigned long long size;
} args_t;

void ioctl_call(args_t *args)
{
    args_t params;

    /* get values */
    ioctl(fd, cmd, params);

    *args = params;
}

void main()
{
    args_t args;
    iotcl_call(&args);
    printf("%d\n", args.id);
}
```

Comment: Why create `second` and then stomp `test` with it? Why not just manipulate `test` directly?

Comment: @tadman This is example code. It's not meant to be useful; it's meant to point something out.

Comment: My question still stands. In what situation would not manipulating it directly be a better option?

Comment: @tadman Like HTNW said, this is test code. Application wise, I have a function that would set values of a struct from an ioctl call. I was trying to see if it what I had originally (basically my test code) was valid, or if I should change it.

Comment: I think your example with an ioctl call is much more informative than this contrived one. This dummy structure contains two `int` values, so it's not going to be a big deal to clumsy-copy it. Others might contain self-referential pointers that *could* be a problem. If you can better illustrate what you're actually doing you can be assured what you're doing is correct.

Comment: I wish people would post their actual code *first*! In your updated `ioctl_call` example, 1) you probably meant to pass `&params`, not `params`. 2) then you can see that just passing `args` is the same type (`args_t *`).

Answer (score 4):

```
void func(test_t * test)
{
    test_t second;
    second.x = 2;
    second.y = 3;

    *test = second;
 }
```

This code is perfectly valid, although less-than-optimal.

It would be illegal to return the *address of* `second`, but that's not what's happening. When you say `*test = second`, you're assigning the *value* of `second` to the dereferenced pointer. The compiler will generate code to copy *each element* of the structure.

The reason it is not ideal is because of that copy. Instead, consider this:

```
void func(test_t * test)
{
    test->x = 2;
    test->y = 3;
 }
```

In this way, the compiler will assign directly to the fields of the pointed-to structure.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! For some reason, I was overthinking and was worried that the second was going to be on the stack, and once the function call ended, the values were going to be garbage.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `test` is local to the function `func` and that changing its value is not visible outside of the function.

However, you're not changing the value of `test`.  You're *dereferencing* the memory location it points to and writing to that location.  In this case, `test` contains the address of the `first` variable in `main`.

So when you assign to `*test` in `func` you're actually assigning to `first` in `main`.  That's why you can see the results outside of the function.

So this code will work as you expect, although it is not optimal.  As mentioned in another answer, rather that assigning values to a local instance of a struct then assigning that to the dereferenced pointer you can simply dereference the pointer and write to each field directly.

```
void func(test_t * test)
{
    test->x = 2;
    test->y = 3;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was thinking about the classic "returning an array declared inside a function" and how those values would be garbage. That's why I was worried about this example.